# Does Redis hash the whole key if curly braces aren't added to the key

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis and have been studying this article on Redis' website about Cluster Specification (https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/). The article mentions hashtags and provides examples of both Ruby and C code. My understanding is that even if you do not include a substring within curly braces in the key but instead hash the entire key on the client side to determine the shard (and a slot within that shard) for the key, it will work as if you had included the entire key within curly braces. When I ran the CLUSTER KEYSLOT command on my key, Redis returned the same number that my client-side application returned when it hashed the whole key. Our aim in doing so is to distribute data evenly among multiple shards. I am not concerned with pipelining or performing MSET or MGET operations. Is my understanding of Curly Braces correct, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, if no curly brace found, it takes the whole key to calculate the slot number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

I added this sentence because StackOverflow requires at least 30 characters for an answer.

Comment: Thank you and on a different note I watch your videos about Redis stuff every now and then, great work sir, appreciate it.